# Redcar mess up my gems

Tags: rubygems, redcar

I recently read somewhere here on SO that Redcar could be a good option as a Ruby editor. But after I installed: `sudo gem install redcar`, it not only couldn't initialize, but also messed up all my gem system.

Look what happens when I try to run:

```
$ redcar
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find redcar (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.0, actionpack-3.1.3, actionpack-3.1.0, activemodel-3.1.3, activemodel-3.1.0, activerecord-3.1.0, activeresource-3.1.0, activesupport-3.1.3, activesupport-3.1.0, addressable-2.2.6, archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, arel-2.2.1, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0146.1, builder-3.0.0, bundler-1.0.21, capybara-1.1.1, childprocess-0.3.0, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.2.0, colored-1.2, columnize-0.3.6, columnize-0.3.5, cucumber-1.0.6, daemons-1.1.8, deepopenstruct-0.1.2, diff-lcs-1.1.3, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-0.12.10, execjs-1.2.13, factory_girl-2.4.2, ffi-1.0.11, flay-1.4.3, flog-2.5.3, gherkin-2.4.21, git-1.2.5, haml-3.1.4, haml-3.1.3, heroku-2.8.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, jquery-rails-1.0.19, jruby-openssl-0.7.6.1, json-1.6.5, json-1.6.3, launchy-2.0.5, libv8-3.3.10.4-x86-linux, linecache19-0.5.12, lucene-0.5.0.beta.1, mail-2.3.0, mime-types-1.17.2, minitest-1.6.0, multi_json-1.0.4, net-ftp-list-3.2.1, net-sftp-2.0.5, net-ssh-2.3.0, nokogiri-1.5.0, pg-0.13.1, plugin_manager-1.5, polyglot-0.3.3, progressbar-0.9.2, rack-1.3.6, rack-1.3.5, rack-cache-1.1, rack-cache-1.0.3, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rails-3.1.0, rails_best_practices-1.7.2, railties-3.1.0, rake-0.9.2.2, rake-0.8.7, rcov-0.9.10, rdoc-3.12, rdoc-2.5.8, redcar-bundles-0.3, redcar-icons-0.3, redcar-javamateview-0.2, redcar-jruby-0.1, redcar-svnkit-0.2, reek-1.2.8, rest-client-1.6.7, riddle-1.5.1, rspec-2.6.0, rspec-core-2.6.4, rspec-expectations-2.6.0, rspec-mocks-2.6.0, rspec-rails-2.6.1, ruby-blockcache-0.2, ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25, ruby-debug19-0.11.6, ruby-tmdb-0.2.1, ruby2ruby-1.3.1, ruby_core_source-0.1.5, ruby_parser-2.3.1, rubygems-update-1.8.18, rubyzip-0.9.5, sass-3.1.12, sass-rails-3.1.5, selenium-webdriver-2.17.0, sequel-3.20.0, sexp_processor-3.0.10, simplecov-0.5.4, simplecov-html-0.5.3, sinatra-1.0, spoon-0.0.1, sprockets-2.0.3, sqlite3-1.3.5, sqlite3-1.3.4, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.3, swt-0.12, taps-0.3.23, term-ansicolor-1.0.7, therubyracer-0.9.9, thin-1.3.1, thinking-sphinx-2.0.11, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.31, uglifier-1.2.2, uglifier-1.0.3, xpath-0.1.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/redcar:18:in `<main>'
```

And when I try to update:

```
$ sudo gem update --system
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
Updating rubygems-update
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.18
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
Installing RubyGems 1.8.18
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.13.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x97fd90c> 1.1.2"]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/psych_tree.rb:3:in `<module:Gem>': uninitialized constant Psych::Visitors (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/psych_tree.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems.rb:667:in `load_yaml'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:235:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:178:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.18/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from setup.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

What should I do? If there is no solution to Redcar, at least I would like to get my gem system back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from https://redcar.lighthouseapp.com/projects/25090/tickets/575

I got one similar problem when update gems today:

> WARNING: Invalid .gemspec format in '/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/specifications/redcar-0.12.gemspec'

and I juse changed the gemspec like this

Original:

```
s.add_development_dependency(%q, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0x99fa778> 1.1.2"])
```

New:

```
s.add_development_dependency(%q, [">= 1.1.2"])
```